# How to get a redirected url without using a Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get a redirected url from another url without using a selenium object. I have an url like:

```
     http://registry.theknot.com/track/View?lt=RetailerGVR&r=325404419&rt=12160&a=994&st=RegistryProfile&ss=LinkedRegistries&sp=Logo
```

and it gets redirected to:

```
     http://www.target.com/RegistryGiftGiverCmd?isPreview=false&status=completePageLink&registryType=WD&isAjax=false&listId=NjPO_i-DoIafZPZSFhaBRw&clkid=2gTTqGRwsXS4x%3AexW%3ATGBxiqUkWXSi0It0P5VM0&lnm=Online+Tracking+Link&afid=The+Knot%2C+Inc.+and+Subsidiaries&ref=tgt_adv_xasd0002
```

when is opened by some browser.

I want to avoid instancing a Selenium object and raise a Firefox/Chrome process just to get the redirected URL. Is there any other better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If this is just an HTTP redirect, [`urllib.request`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html)/[`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) in the standard library can follow redirects just fine, as can third-party HTTP client libraries like [`requests`](http://python-requests.org) and [`PycURL`](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net). In fact, in the simplest use cases, they do so automatically.

So, just:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> original_url = 'http://registry.theknot.com/track/View?lt=RetailerGVR&r=325404419&rt=12160&a=994&st=RegistryProfile&ss=LinkedRegistries&sp=Logo'
>>> u = urllib.request.urlopen(original_url)
>>> print(u.url)
http://www.target.com/RegistryGiftGiverCmd?isPreview=false&status=completePageLink&registryType=WD&isAjax=false&listId=NjPO_i-DoIafZPZSFhaBRw&clkid=0b5XTmU%3A5WbqRETSYD20AQKOUkWXSGQgQSquVU0&lnm=Online+Tracking+Link&afid=The+Knot%2C+Inc.+and+Subsidiaries&ref=tgt_adv_xasd0002
```

But if you just want the data, you don't even need that:

```
>>> data = u.read()
```

That's the contents of the redirected request.

(For Python 2.x, just replace `urllib.request` with `urllib2` and it works the same.)

---

The only reason you'd need to use Selenium (or another browser automation and/or JS-environment library) is if the redirect is done through in-page JavaScript. Which it usually isn't, and isn't in this case. There's no reason to go outside the standard library, talk to another app, etc. for simple things like this.